# CQLSH client - module' object has no attribute 'parse_options

Tags: php, python, cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

I'm trying to access my Cassandra server through a CQLSH client to import a huge CSV file. I'm getting a `module' object has no attribute 'parse_options` error.

**I run the follow command:**

```
cqlsh XXX.XXX.XX.XX XXXX --cqlversion="3.4.2" --execute="copy evolvdso.teste from '2016-10-26 15:25:10.csv' WITH DELIMITER =',' AND HEADER=TRUE --debug";
```

**This is the debug and error message that follows:**

```
Starting copy of evolvdso.teste with columns ['ref_equip', 'date', 'load', 'ptd_assoc'].
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 1133, in onecmd
    self.handle_statement(st, statementtext)
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 1170, in handle_statement
    return custom_handler(parsed)
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 1834, in do_copy
    rows = self.perform_csv_import(ks, cf, columns, fname, opts)
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 1846, in perform_csv_import
    csv_options, dialect_options, unrecognized_options = copyutil.parse_options(self, opts)


AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse_options'
```

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you running? Are you unconvinced that it could be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12284, which I linked on your other comment?

Comment: Im running version 3.7. Yes, i saw it , thank you. Maybe it's the same problem. I found a workaround, im using this: https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader to load the CSV to my remote database and it's working very well!

Comment: I also used pip to install the cqlsh client. Yes i assume is the same problem. :)

Comment: It's usually best to use the cqlsh version packaged with Cassandra distribution. They are not meant to be cross-version, and it's sometimes not obvious which version is published in that pypi package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Has the same issue when I use `cqlsh` from `pip install cqlsh`.
Try just use cassandra's tool `cqlsh`

`sudo docker run -it cassandra /usr/bin/cqlsh`

Refer to [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12284)

Comment: After almost 3 years i still came back here. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer in 2020:**

To use cassandra's cqlsh use `docker run -it cassandra /opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh`

If you are using bitnami's cassandra image, cqlsh is located at `/opt/bitnami/cassandra/bin/cqlsh`

And then `COPY keyspace.table TO '/tmp/my_table.csv';`

Answer (score 2):

I met a similar problem, the **reason** for my scenario is that the default cqlsh path is `/usr/local/bin/cqlsh`. (check with command `$ which cqlsh`)

**Solution**: using Cassandra shipped `/usr/bin/cqlsh` to connect the Cassandra server or run some command. For example, connect to Cassandra server using command:

```
$ /usr/bin/cqlsh <cassandra_listen_ip>
```

OR run command with

```
$ /usr/bin/cqlsh <cassandra_listen_ip> -e "<command>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the pip version has some issues, you should install via the official packages instead like:

```
apt install wget apt-transport-https
wget -q -O - https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | apt-key add -
sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.list'
apt update
apt install -y cassandra
```

Note this will also include the cassandra services, so if you don't want those to be running you may have to manually disable them.