# Cassandra cqlsh unable to import cqlshhandling

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-18.04, cqlsh

When executing the following command:

```
/usr/bin/cqlsh 127.0.0.1
```

Error encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 169, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cql3handling, cqlhandling, pylexotron, sslhandling, cqlshhandling
ImportError: cannot import name cqlshhandling
```

Even though I found the cqlshhandling.py script in the following directory:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlshlib

The command `which cqlsh` shows /usr/local/bin/cqlsh. This is from `pip install cqlsh`.

Currently used command is from cassandra itself. What do I set to get cqlsh running?

Comment: How did you install cqlsh?  Sometimes reinstalling via PIP can fix this `pip install cqlsh`.  Otherwise, check your PATH and make sure that your environment is using Python 2.7.11+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is stated in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793949/6867961).

Find the path where cqlshlib exists:

```
find /usr/lib/ -name cqlshlib
```

The path obtained (in my case) is:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlshlib
```

Export the path using below variable name:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

---

cqlsh installed via pip DO NOT help and COPY function will lead to the following error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'parse_options'
```

---

Comment: Thanks for posting this!  Glad you figured it out.