# cqlsh: error: no such option: --request-timeout

Tags: cql, cqlsh

On my Mac, I am using cqlsh version 5.0.1

On my Ubuntu, I am also on cqlsh 5.0.1

(both queried with `which cqlsh`)

I run the following command on both boxes (both have a cassandra instance locally)

```
cqlsh --request-timeout=30 -k authks 127.0.0.1 -e "copy users to 'users.tmp.csv' with escape='\"' and null='null' and maxrequests=2 and INGESTRATE=10000 and CHUNKSIZE=200;
```

On Mac it works. On Ubuntu, I get the following error:

> cqlsh: error: no such option: --request-timeout

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you try `--connect-timeout` in ubuntu?

Comment: I get the no such option error when I try it on Ubuntu

Comment: `cqlsh --help` will provide with `--connect-timeout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to using `pip install cqlsh` which is not supported by the apache team.

The answer is to install cassandra properly from the apache cassandra site. Even then you may have some path issues as you will have two python libraries with `cqlshlib` in them.

Hence, having installed cassandra, you may want to visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197362/unable-to-open-cqlsh-apache-cassandra-importerror-no-module-named-cqlshlib/61593928#61593928) for further debugging